# discord.py on_message event error

Tags: python, discord.py

I have two on_messages events:

The problem is that when both of them are in the same code only the one that is in lower position works. When I remove it the other one works and the opposite. both of them finish with await client.process_commands(message).

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    contents = message.content.split(" ") #contents is a list type
    for word in contents:
        if word.upper() in chat_filter:
            if not message.author.id in bypass_list:
                await client.delete_message(message)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hey! You are not allowed to use that word here!")
                await client.process_commands(message)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('ping'):
   await client.send_message(message.channel, 'pong')
   await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: please add some code or add a description...

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the `on_message(message)` function when you call `def` twice.  This overrides the above `async def on_message(message)`.

What you should do is merge the two together into one function.

I highly recommend you look into the discord.py [examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py) they have a premade basic bot with a already built in command parser.